# RESTLET get parameters from HTML page

Tags: java, jsp, restlet

I want to develop an web application using RESTLET where i want to send arguments from jsp page. as far as server side code is concerned i have written resource classes in RESTLET.

But the main point is RESTLEt uses xml for communication, how can we communicate with RESTLET from jsp/html page.

Answer (score 0):

RESTLET uses XML/JSON over HTTP and JSP/HTML are capable to do HTTP communication. XML will basically go inside the body of HTTP messages. So there are no compatibility issues, simply follow any tutorial to learn about sending HTTP requests from JSP to your REST server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, i searched on google but could not find anything relevant, Can u please share a code snippet where on client side we have HTML5 and on server side RESTLET is used.

Answer (score 0):

RESTlet can additionally return HTML (or any number of other formats) over HTTP if that is what you require to display, it could even be able to parse jsps to create the HTML with a little work.  Basically at an initial level Restlet is largely format agnostic providing you with the HTTP protocol support. You communicate with the restlet server by passing HTTP requests in exactly the same way that you would from any HTML page to any other server generating the JSP. the exact details of how and when you need to do this will depend greatly on what you want to use it for, and how, do you want to use the traditional client server model or are you looking for AJAX queries?